# How to access difference path from mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making an upload site. I want to upload image to out folder from my project.

Here's the link to my project:

```
D:/repo/abc/abc.WebUI.Back
```

I want to upload image to:

```
D:/repo/abc/abc.WebUI.POS/images/abc-promo
```

I tried using this:

```
string filePath = "";
            string fileName = null;
            var path = @"~\..\repo\abc\abc.WebUI.POS\images\abc-promo\";
            if (vm.file != null && vm.file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path),
                           Path.GetFileName(vm.file.FileName));
                fileName = vm.file.FileName;
                vm.file.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
```

I there's an error.

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Simply use path like ~\repo\abc\abc.WebUI.POS\images\abc-promo\ no need of..

Answer (score 1):

When you put a ".." in

```
var path = @"~\..\repo\abc\abc.WebUI.POS\images\abc-promo\";
```

it could be used to escape up the directory, and this type of action is considered to be a security vulnerability. Google for "double dot attack", and you will know why. Instead of your path variable the way you assigned, use the below.

```
Server.MapPath("~/images/abc-promo/")
```

and make sure you dont start to map the directory outside your webfolder as you did in your code block as this "repo\abc\abc.WebUI.POS". When you put a "~" (tidle), it means "start from the root folder of the web app). Hope this solves your issue.